# How to add ON UPDATE/DELETE CASCADE behaviour to generated column foreign key in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I would like to add an "ON UPDATE CASCADE" to a foreign key constraint (a polymorphic foreign key) on a generated column.

Here is what I did:

```
// Created two parent tables

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "SCH_A".parent_tab_a
(
    id bigint NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 CACHE 1 ),
    name text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT parent_tab_a_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT parent_tab_a_nkey UNIQUE (name)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "SCH_A".parent_tab_b
(
    id bigint NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 CACHE 1 ),
    name text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT parent_tab_b_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT parent_tab_b_nkey UNIQUE (name)
)

// Created a child table.

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "SCH_A".child_tab
(
    id bigint NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 CACHE 1 ),
    name text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    parentname text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,    
    parentcode text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    "parent$parent_tab_a" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
    CASE
       WHEN (parentcode = 'parent_tab_a'::text) THEN parentname
       ELSE NULL::text
    END) STORED,
    "parent$parent_tab_b" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
    CASE
       WHEN (parentcode = 'parent_tab_b'::text) THEN parentname
       ELSE NULL::text
    END) STORED,
    CONSTRAINT child_tab_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT "child_parent$parent_tab_a_fk" FOREIGN KEY ("parent$parent_tab_a")
        REFERENCES "SCH_A".parent_tab_a (name) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT "child_parent$parent_tab_b_fk" FOREIGN KEY ("parent$parent_tab_b")
        REFERENCES "SCH_A".parent_tab_b (name) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE 
)
```

When I ran the command to create the child table, I got the following error message:

```
ERROR:  invalid ON UPDATE action for foreign key constraint containing generated column
SQL state: 42601
```

The message is clear enough. What I am trying to do is to apparently not possible on Postgresql. However, I absolutely need to achieve an ON UPDATE CASCADE and also ON DELETE CASCADE between the child and the parent tables. The behaviour I wish to achieve is that if someone updates (or deletes) a row in either parent_tab_a or parent_tab_b tables, I wish the corresponding row in the child table to be updated (or deleted)

Is there some other way to do this other than with ON UPDATE CASCADE, ON DELETE CASCADE statements ?

Comment: The issue is not `ON UPDATE CASCADE, ON DELETE CASCADE` it is `...containing generated column`. A generated column can not be part of a FK. See [Create table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html): *This clause creates the column as a generated column. The column cannot be written to, and when read the result of the specified expression will be returned.*

Comment: You can use triggers instead of relying on the foreign key constraints' cascading actions. Triggers in PostgreSQL can be used to define custom actions in response to changes in the database, such as updates or deletions in a table.

Comment: Yes, I think I will have to use the triggers alright. And to reply to the first poster above, you are right also, indeed the documentation says generated columns cannot be used as FKs, though I am for some reason permitted to use them that way nonetheless.